# How to display XML file in IE

Tags: internet-explorer

I've installed Internet Explorer 9 beta version. In thisd i can not display xml file(Its not showing any thing) . How to make it visible in IE9 beta?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Read this thread](http://social.answers.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/InternetExplorer/thread/ebc5c7e2-6b30-4f0f-acb3-ffe6df33c173) and see if it helps.

Comment: This still isn't fixed after almost three years?

Comment: Nooo. Link is broken. I can't seem to figure out the solution for this IE issue.